# ui elements not working on windows phone 8 maps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

i am trying to create a map object on windows phone 8 and nothing shows yet i have no errors on my code. help me heres the code:

the ui element doesnt show on the map and yet i created a polygon, and a rectangle element on the grid.
here is my xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
x:Class="Fisheries.Landing_site"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">
<!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Landing Sites" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" Center="5.354683, 24.644135" ZoomLevel="10" LandmarksEnabled="True" PedestrianFeaturesEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and here is my cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Device.Location;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace Fisheries
{
public partial class Landing_site : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Landing_site()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdateMap();

        /*   Rectangle MyRectangle = new Rectangle();
           MyRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
           MyRectangle.Height = 20;
           MyRectangle.Width = 20;
           MyRectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
           MyRectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);*/
    }
    public void UpdateMap()
    {
       Map drew = new Map();
       drew.Margin = new Thickness(-12, 0, 0, 0);

       ContentPanel.Children.Add(drew);
       drew.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(5.354683, 24.644135), 3.5D);

        //creating the grid
       Grid MyGrid = new Grid();
       MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
       MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
       MyGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

       //Creating a Rectangle
       Rectangle MyRectangle = new Rectangle();
       MyRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
       MyRectangle.Height = 20;
       MyRectangle.Width = 40;
       MyRectangle.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 0);
       MyRectangle.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

      //adding a rectangle to the grid

        MyGrid.Children.Add(MyRectangle);

        //Creating a Polygon
        Polygon MyPolygon = new Polygon();
        MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(2, 0));
        MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(22, 0));
        MyPolygon.Points.Add(new Point(2, 40));
        MyPolygon.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        MyPolygon.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        MyPolygon.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
        MyPolygon.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);

        //addding a new polygon to the grid

        //Creating a MapOverlay and adding the Grid to it.
        MapOverlay MyOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        MyOverlay.Content = MyGrid;

        MyGrid.Children.Add(MyPolygon);

        //setting the geolocation cordiante to work on some polygon to show on the map
        MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(5.354683, 24.644135);

        //this is where is set the position overlay to a specific location on the map
        MyOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, 0.5);

        //Creating a MapLayer and adding the MapOverlay to it
        MapLayer MyLayer = new MapLayer();
        MyLayer.Add(MyOverlay);
        MyMap.Layers.Add(MyLayer);
    }



}
```

}